# iPhone GameKit, GKScore

Tags: iphone, gamekit

As I understand when you call 'reportScoreWithCompletionHandler' you should set value property. If you don't have any scores and set fro example value=10, it will be submitted to leaderboard, but if you try to submit less points after or even negative points, leaderboard will not be changed.

Is there any opportunity to reduce player scores or even make them negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to reset or decrease a user score, any score submission with a lower value than the player's current score will be ignored. Trust me, I've tried...